# Drawing bitmap to screen are blurred???

Tags: ios, bitmap, core-graphics

I draw something finger touch use bitmap.

First I draw the line to bitmap.

Then draw bitmap to the screen.

But the question is using this way,lines are blurred.

Below is a comparison.

[image]

[image]

picture1 is directly drawing onto the screen.
picture2 is using bitmap.
Here is my code:

```
 - (BOOL)CreateBitmapContext:(int)pixelsWide High:(int)pixelsHight
{
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
void *         bitmapData;
int            bitmapByteCount;
int            bitMapBytesPerRow;

bitMapBytesPerRow = (pixelsWide * 4);
bitmapByteCount = (bitMapBytesPerRow * pixelsHight);

colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
bitmapData = malloc(bitmapByteCount);
if (bitmapData == NULL)
{
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return NO;
}
tempContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, pixelsWide, pixelsHight, 8, bitMapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);



if (tempContext == NULL)
{
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    free(bitmapData);
    return NO;
}
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
return YES;
 }


 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
[tool setFirstPoint:p];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
CGPoint previous = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
[tool moveFromPoint:previous toPoint:p];
[tool draw:tempContext];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

myImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (tempContext);// 5
CGContextDrawImage(myContext, rect, myImage);// 6  
}
```

So what wrong with it??

Anyone?

Comment: You should use double height and width for your context on retina devices.

Answer (score 1):

Your device probably has a retina screen. On those screens, you need to allocate a bitmap that is the same pixel resolution of the screen, or it'll be a little blurry when you render it back. The confusing part is if you just do `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` to determine the pixel resolution, then your image will be half the needed pixel resolution. This is because the bounds values represent density-independent points, not pixels. You compensate for this by also reading `[[UIScreen mainscreen] scale]` which will return `2.0` on retina devices.

Comment: Yeah you should multiply the values you're passing into `- (BOOL)CreateBitmapContext:(int)pixelsWide High:(int)pixelsHight` by `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`

Comment: but when I typing the code like this:

        `float scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];

        myBitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, size.width , size.height, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);


    
       if (Retina)
       {
           CGContextScaleCTM(myBitmapContext, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
       }` 

It is still showing  not correct

Comment: Don't set the context scale, change the size of the context you're creating. Aka, unconditionally multiply by scaleFactor in CGBitmapContextCreate (the scale is 1.0 on non-retina screens, so you don't need that if-check).

Comment: But when I do it like this `bitmapBytesPerRow = (size.width * scaleFactor * 4);`
    `bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height * scaleFactor); `
`myBitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, size.width * scaleFactor ,size.height * scaleFactor , 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);`.The context is reduced by half.My fingers are not on top of where the screen drawing.

Comment: `float scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];
    
    bitmapBytesPerRow = (size.width * scaleFactor * 4);


    bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height * scaleFactor);
    
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    
    bitmapData = malloc(bitmapByteCount);
    if (bitmapData == NULL) {
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        return NO;
    }
    
    myBitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, size.width * scaleFactor ,size.height * scaleFactor , 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);`
I modify it just above.